# Wordpress PHP FIle not running

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, select

I have a custom search form on my website with this code:

```
<center>
<form action="orderstatus.php" method="POST">

  <input type="text" name="OrderLineNumber" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</center>
```

And although I call orderstatus.php to action . When I press the submit button I get this Url : blablabla.de/action_page.php?OrderLineNumber=+23563623
This means instead of running orderstatus.php it's running action_page.php

My orderstatus.php is trying to print One Select Row from database like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "*******";
$username = "*******";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM OrderStatus";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() & fetch_assoc() = $_POST["name"] ) {
        echo "<br> Order Line Number: ". $row["OrderLineNumber"]. " - Date Started: ". $row["Date Started"]. " " . $row["Status"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the reason you get that is because wordpress can't find orderstatus.php . Also this method opens a big security issue. Try using something like `add_action` instead.

Comment: where should i put the orderstatus.php ?

Comment: UPDATE : I used include in functions and now Submit button leads to orderstatus.php but it's not compiling . It gives me a 404 Page Not Found with URL : ........../orderstatus.php